# Java, writing a method to calculate batting averages not giving correct output

Tags: java, methods

My calculated average is coming out to 0.0 each time when it shouldn't be. Any help would be appreciated.

The code in my BaseballPlayer class:

```
//BaseballPlayer parameters

String name;
int number;
int singles;
int doubles;
int triples;
int homeRuns;
int atBats;
int walks;
int sacrificeFlies;

//BaseballPlayer constructor method

public BaseballPlayer(String name, int number, int singles, int triples, int homeRuns, int atBats, int walks, 
        int sacrificeFlies)
{
    this.name            =   name;
    this.number          =   number;
    this.singles         =   singles;
    this.triples         =   triples;
    this.homeRuns        =   homeRuns;
    this.atBats          =   atBats;
    this.walks           =   walks;
    this.sacrificeFlies  =   sacrificeFlies;
}

// Batting average
public double getBattingAverage() {
    double average  = ((singles+doubles+triples+homeRuns)/atBats);
    return average;
}
```

The code in my main class:

```
BaseballPlayer player01  =   new BaseballPlayer( "Mr. Business",13,12,13,4,84,63,7);

    System.out.println(player01.getBattingAverage());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of this:

```
double average  = ((singles+doubles+triples+homeRuns)/atBats);
```

try this:

```
double average = (double) (singles + doubles + triples + homeRuns) / atBats;
```

Because the data types for `singles`, `doubles`, `triples`, `homeRuns`, and `atBats` are all `integer`, it's doing the math, getting the result as another `integer` ("0"), and then storing that as a `double` ("0.0") which isn't what you want. By adding `(double)` at the front, you are directing the JVM to cast the result to the data type `double`.

Running your code as posted above, here's the output I see locally:

```
0.0
```

after casting the result to `double`, here's what I see:

```
0.34523809523809523
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, I appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

In order to get a more precise result instead of int, it is required to let JVM know what you want during the calculation process instead of after the calculation. One of the simplest ways is casting the Divisor or Dividend as  double as of above example. 
i.e.

```
double average = ((double) (singles + doubles + triples + homeRuns) / atBats);
```

or

```
double average = ( (singles + doubles + triples + homeRuns) / (double) atBats);
```

In the original code, the behavior would like casting the result from intto double again after whole calculation is completed(below codes section could be reference). The precision has already lost and that's why you could only get 0 instead of of a precise number:

```
double average  = (double) ( (singles+doubles+triples+homeRuns)/ atBats);
```